# How to add extra fields to user profile?

Tags: 7, users

I'd like to add additional fields to the user profile. I'd like user to be able to edit almost all the information I store in the database about him. 
I have some ideas: maybe it's possible to do using form api.

Comment: detail blog is here: http://goo.gl/zxBTBY

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A way to add user fields by code so you can put this in your module.

I have found this: [field_create_field](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.crud.inc/function/field_create_field/7) with in the comments a way to create a field for your user upon enabling your module:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_enable().
 */
function MYMODULE_enable() {
  // Check if our field is not already created.
  if (!field_info_field('field_myField')) {
    $field = array(
        'field_name' => 'field_myField', 
        'type' => 'text', 
    );
    field_create_field($field);

    // Create the instance on the bundle.
    $instance = array(
        'field_name' => 'field_myField', 
        'entity_type' => 'user', 
        'label' => 'My Field Name', 
        'bundle' => 'user', 
        // If you don't set the "required" property then the field wont be required by default.
        'required' => TRUE,
        'settings' => array(
           // Here you inform either or not you want this field showing up on the registration form.
            'user_register_form' => 1,
        ),
        'widget' => array(
            'type' => 'textfield',
            'weight' => '1',
        ), 
    );
    field_create_instance($instance);
  }
}
```

Comment: I found this very useful [page](http://steindom.com/articles/exporting-and-creating-field-definitions-drupal-7) which explains how to export fields that were created with the UI. This export can then be used with field_create_field and field_create_instance to do everything programmatically

Comment: Thanks, this was very useful - have an idea how to auto assign the weight as well?

Comment: you can add `'weight' => '1',` to the widget array in the `$instance` I'll add it in my answer.

Comment: For complex cases, it is useful to first add the field manually on `/admin/config/people/accounts/fields`, then use [Field Inspector](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_inspector) on `/admin/config/development/field-inspector` to export the field and field instance definition arrays for use in code like the above.

Comment: To keep DB clean, you may also want to implement an hook_uninstall to delete the field.
`function MYMODULE_uninstall() {field_delete_field('field_myField');}`

Answer (score 38):

I found the page hard to find, but at /admin/config/people/accounts/fields you can add fields to users.

Comment: Thank you, but can i do it using form api? I need more functionality.

Comment: what is it you want to do, that isn't possible with fields?

Comment: I already created my own fields in the Drupal table `users`. "Fields" create new fields outside the table `users`.

Comment: that's how drupal works, why do you want to store the fields inside the users table?

Comment: It's more conveniente way to do it in my opinion. By the way in order to add extra fields i use `hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)`

Comment: the benefits of the drupal way are amongst others: support for revisions, support for input/output widget, integrates with views, ... So my advice is to do it the drupal way ;p

Comment: Attiks is right to add new fields easily. Basically it's the easiest method and i think so.
Moreover, there is a pretty clearer tutorials which is step by step to learn and do the same thing for your Drupal website. You may access that tutorial following the following link: http://drupalfun.blogspot.com/2012/06/how-to-add-extra-fields-to-user-profile.html

Comment: Note that using the form api is still a drupal way with an advantage that if you put it in a module you can reuse your code to create the fields on another website instead of clicking it together on every website that you create that needs this functionality. Now your just enable your module and your done.

Comment: How to access the data of newly created field? it doesnt come with global $user object

Answer (score 5):

Profile in D7 is a bit weird. The [profile2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) module may do what you need.

Answer (score 4):

In Drupal 7, use this process to add a new or existing field with different field types (such as Image, Tags field etc.) to the user profile:

1. Enable the **Field UI** module.
2. Go to "**Admin → Configuration → People: Account settings**" in the admin menu, and then to "**Manage fields**" (the second tab).

   (Alternatively, use the direct path in the URL: `/admin/config/people/accounts/fields`).
3. Fill out the "Add new field" or "Add existing field" line at the bottom of the form and click "Save".

Answer (score 1):

Which kind of fields do you want to add?

- If this is a social networking site and you are adding privacy settings fields, use the [Privacy Per User](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/89483/privacy-settings-page-for-a-drupal-based-social-network-site-recommended-modul/89484#89484) module.
- If you wants to add tabs or accordion fields, use the field_group module to add new groups on the user account fields (URL: /admin/config/people/accounts/fields).
- And if you want different fields for different roles, use the [profile2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) module.