# How to change the user profile edit page?

Tags: users

What is the best way to change the user profile edit page? I need to add a new field alongside the password.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add extra fields to user profile?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8253/how-to-add-extra-fields-to-user-profile)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add new fields to the users profile page at admin/config/people/accounts/fields

You can also manipulate the form by implementing `hook_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)` and `hook_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)`

To add new profile pages you can use the [Profile 2](https://drupal.org/project/profile2) module.

You can also [edit the user edit template](http://buildingwebs.wordpress.com/2011/05/11/customizing-edit-user-page-in-drupal-7/) by implementing [hook_theme](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7)().

Answer (score 0):

In drupal 7     /admin/config/people/accounts/fields
Here you can add and change certain fields for the user profile.
You may want to check out the module profile2 as well: https://drupal.org/project/profile2