# Using Flags for 'Out of office'

Tags: 7, panels, flags

I'm trying to use flags to create 'Out of office' functionality for my site users where user profiles are built into panels.

- How can I add a flag where user can only see flag on his own profile
- When user flags 'out of office' he gets displayed with a text field and then that text    field get rendered within user profile displaying 'out of office' message.

  Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this thread : http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8253/how-to-add-extra-fields-to-user-profile . You'll probably find the two most upvoted answers worth exploring.

Comment: create a user flag... make sure global flag checkbox is empty (unchecked). Under flagged message, type 'out of office'. Check mark the box that says, "display link in user profile". It's not rocket science... did you even try?

Comment: Thanks and Yes - I did try and it works but What I want is the flag to be only displayed on logged in user's profile and not within other user profiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved 'Out of office' flag functionality using rules module.

Placed an out-of-office flag on user profile and set visibility rules (panels) to show flag only if its user's own profile
Within flags used flagging form to capture user out-of-office message
Added an extra field 'out-of-office' within user's profile.
Created a rule on flagging-event to populate 'Out-office-field' with text from flagging form.
Created a rule to delete the text from 'out-of-office' field on unflagging